# Javascript get and set availability in browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecmascript-5

Which browsers do not support the get and set methods for object prototypes? I believe this is a feature of ES5, an I know it works in Chrome, but I am wondering if it is safe to use for ajax apps. Here's an example:

```
var foo = function () {};
foo.prototype = {
    get name () {
        return this._name;
    },
    set name (n) {
        this._name = n || "bar";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a compatibility table for you.

http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

See the `Getter in property initializer` and `Setter in property initializer` rows.

According to the table:

- Firefox 4
- Safari 5
- Chrome 7-11

Other browsers (including IE9) are not given a `Yes` or `No`, so perhaps they're untested. I'm pretty sure IE9 supports it.

Comment: Sorry, no time to test the other ones :)

Comment: "No support (notably in IE6-8) means that the script will trigger a syntax error." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get